# Parsing data via `re.match` and placing it into tuple/list/dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently parsing a large amount of data (user data) and matching it into various groups to for later use.

Im not sure on the best approach do I place the data into a tuple list like so

`[(data1value,data2value,data3value,data4value)]`.

Then convert all the tuples in the list into a dictionary to give them a better description and catagorise them for easier user later, like so?

`{Username:data1value,Account:data2value,Description:data3value,SID:data4value}`

Using the Username as the key and the rest of the data nested?

**Code Snippet Showing Parsing and `re.match` process.**

```
data1 = matches.group(2).lstrip().strip()
data2 = matches.group(6).lstrip().strip()
data3 = matches.group(8).lstrip().strip()
data4 = matches.group(10).lstrip().strip()

details.append((data1, data2, data3, data4))

for item in details:
    print item
```

**Output**

```
('value', 'value', 'value', 'value)
('value', 'value', 'value', 'value)
('value', 'value', 'value', 'value)
```

Comment: What is the source of your data? There's probably an easier way to do this.

Comment: Output from a `subprocess` call. Then reading the stdout line by line

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if you're asking how you should store your data, that depends on how you intend to access it.

Comment: well initially storage can be temprary in the most appropriate form. Which is what I am trying to find out in this post. I may write the data to a db later but for now it just needs to be stored in memory

Comment: Right, but how are you actually going to access it? Dictionaries are useful if you need to access individual elements by one particular value, but aren't necessary if you're just going to loop over all elements.

Comment: more data will be added to the dictionary so looping will be needed

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to use that data after collecting it.

If you intend to  make it shorter, you can skip a step and just write it directly into a dict() instead of creating a tuple. But as long as you have a dict() at the end it should be flexible and accessible.

Comment: Im not entirely sure how to go from a list of values to a dictionary with key value pairs.

Comment: It is possible using loops you could return a list of dictionaries, so `for a,b,c,d in details: data.append({"Username":a,"Account":b,"Description":c,"SID":d})`

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will turn your tuple-list into a list of dictionaries with the provided field names:

```
fields = ['Username', 'Account', 'Description', 'SID']
dicts = [dict(zip(fields, values)) for values in details]
```

You can also use a similar approach to collect a list of dictionaries immediately without the tuple-step.

Comment: nice and simple, just like me